# Handle return type of a function

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript and facing a issue:

```
type TLang = 'en' | 'ar'

export const getIntlLang = (): 'en' | 'ar' => {
  const validLangs = ['en', 'ar'];
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  let userLang: TLang = 'ar';
  const customLang = urlParams.get('language') || '';
  if (customLang && validLangs.includes(customLang)) {
    userLang = customLang; // **Type 'string' is not assignable to type** '"en" | "ar"'
  } else {
    const language: TLang =
      window.localStorage && window.localStorage.getItem('language');
    if (language && validLangs.indexOf(language) >= 0) {
      userLang = language;
    }
  }
  updateLang(userLang);
  return userLang;
};
```

I want the return type of the function to be specifically 'en' or 'ar'. I'm getting the error here that: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"en" | "ar"'. How should I fix this?

Comment: I want the return type of function to be 'en' or 'ar' specifically. Not string

Comment: @MauriceNino Then what change should i do to make sure i only 'en' or 'ar'

Comment: Your return is a specific enum value whose base type is string. So make your enum class

Comment: As I said, the code is already handling the null case, in case of null it will return 'ar'. How do I make typescript know this

Comment: @MauriceNino How does returning TLang solve the problem?

Comment: @MauriceNino because "en" and "ar" are a strings... no. in ts there are type literals. for ts 'en' is not string but custom type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what solved the problem for me:

```
export const getIntlLang = (): TLang => {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  let userLang: TLang = 'ar';
  const customLang = urlParams.get(LANGUAGE_KEY);
  if (customLang === 'ar' || customLang === 'en') {
    userLang = customLang;
  } else {
  const language =
    window.localStorage && window.localStorage.getItem(LANGUAGE_KEY);
    if (language === 'en' || language === 'ar') {
      userLang = language;
    }
  }
  updateLang(userLang);
  return userLang;
};
```

Comment: yes, sting literal and sting are not same type for typescript.  if (language === 'en' || language === 'ar')... from now ts compiler can infer type literal ... for ts 'ar' is not string but type 'ar'. this is good solution